# Is Google using canvas fingerprinting for their ads?

Tags: google, fingerprinting

Given the fact that canvas fingerprinting is a hype, I raise my eyebrows whenever I see `fillText` or `strokeText` in JavaScript code executing on websites. I noticed that Google uses some of these eye raising codes in their ad delivery code. For example:

- https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/cached_libs/createjs_2015.11.26_54e1c3722102182bb133912ad4442e19_min.js
- https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sadbundle/1253442454509157695/libs/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js

Both contain `fillText` and `strokeText`. What is going on here? Why would Google need to draw text strings? This is a massive document and my JavaScript knowledge is too poor to analyze it all.

Comment: We generally don't do large code reviews. Perhaps this question belongs on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are, those files aren't really evidence of it, they are just minified bundles of some of the [CreateJS libraries](https://github.com/CreateJS).

> Both contain `fillText` and `strokeText`. What is going on here?

The CreateJS libraries are mainly used for canvas drawing, and there is a "private" function which will draw text, [`_drawTextLine`](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/631cdffb85eff9413dab43b4676f059b4232d291/src/easeljs/display/Text.js#L401-L402). Those are the instances of `fillText`/`strokeText` you see.

> Why would Google need to draw text strings?

There are many possible reasons to draw text to a canvas. I don't know what you found these files being used with, but I suspect it is something that makes heavy use of canvas drawing. Perhaps some HTML5 ads?

If anyone competent were going to use `fillText`/`strokeText` for fingerprinting, I don't think they would load up a full canvas drawing library to draw some text, as I can't see it being very helpful for the actual difficult part of the image recognition code.